# Trying to set up the action bar but now have 'R cannot be resolved to a variable' errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file

Hi I am trying to learn how to write an android app in Eclipse Juno with the latest Android SDK and tools all for 64bit windows 7, in case that makes any difference.

I had previously got through the tutorials at https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#ReceiveIntent

All was working fine until i got to the lesson 'Setting up the Action Bar' where it asked whether the app should support Android 3.0 and above only or 2.1 and above.  I chose 2.1 and above and followed those instructions to include the support libraries for compatibility.  After I did that and set up the java build path, I am now getting many errors in the basic app that state 'R cannot be resolved to a variable'.

I have searched quite extensively and tried many previous solutions but no luck.  I am thinking there may be a conflict as I have my previous app (before adding the action bar) also in the package in eclipse.  Should I remove it and try to rebuild with just the new one, and the compatibility folders?

Any new ideas that I can try are welcome.  I can post any code that might help - it is just basic tutorial stuff.

Cheers,
LRW

Comment: try to look at the problem tab of your ide. Any compilation error can stop generation or R in android.

Comment: I don' see any error on console.  I'm not sure if i'm looking at right problem tab though.  I didn't see one with that name.

Answer (score 0):

See if you have imported:
`android.R`
if yes, delete that import :)

Comment: no, I already checked that one from other solutions to similar issues.